# How to trickle down reusable shapes updates to diagrams

Tags: visio

I am creating my own custom shapes for some of my enterprise architecture works and thought of taking the stencil route, the question i have is if i am using custom shapes from my stencils in my visio diagrams, and later on if i go and update those shapes in stencils, does those change reflect back to all diagrams? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify the masters in a document all instances of those masters in the same document will be updated. Shapes you created in other documents will not be updated because when you drag-and-drop from a stencil to another document the master is copied into the document.

If you are modifying masters using the automation API make sure you call [Master.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766060%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [Master.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766772%28v=office.14%29.aspx). If you don’t changes to groups and shape counts won’t propagate to instance shapes.